# How can I separate Perl variables from text in interpolated strings?

Tags: perl, variables, interpolation

Consider:

```
print "    $foo", "AAAAAAAA", $foo, "BBBBBBBB";
```

Let's say I want to use this code with a `print <<EOF;`:

```
print <<EOF;
    $fooAAAAAAAA$fooBBBBBBBB";
EOF
```

That won't work, because Perl thinks I have a variable called `$fooAAAAAAAA`. How can I easily use `print <<` with such lines when I have a long test to print?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use `${foo}`:

```
print <<EOF;
    ${foo}AAAAAAAA${foo}BBBBBBBB";
EOF
```

Comment: as a small aside, this method also works in a normal string: print "${foo}bar";

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way to do it using `printf`:

```
printf << EOF, $foo, $foo;
   %dAAAAA%dBBBBBBB 
EOF
```

That is, assuming you want to print `$foo` as a decimal number.  You can substitute `%d` with whatever format you need.

Answer (score 0):

And another answer, based on non interpolated strings, which I think is the most appropriate.

```
print <<'EOF';
    $fooAAAAAAAA$fooBBBBBBBB";
EOF
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators